# want one more option in same jsp page while clicking another link

Tags: java, jsp

i have one jsp page(suppose asdf) with in that there have 2 links(suppose link.ab,link.cd). both are points to same jsp(suppose qwerty) and there 3 columns available..but if i will click link.ab then 3 columns will display and if i will click link.cd then there should display 4 columns how it will i m not getting any idea..
i m trying this code but getting error of **Request processing failed; nested exception**

```
<tbody>
<tr>
 <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${addQuestionLink}"></c:when>
<td class="label">
    <form:label path="ins_org">
        <span class="requiredFieldMarker"><fmt:message key="label.requiredMarker"/></span>
        <fmt:message key="label.institute"/><fmt:message key="label.postfix"/>
    </form:label>
</td>
<td class="data">
    <form:select path="ins_org" >
    <form:option value=""><fmt:message key="label.general.select"/></form:option>
    <form:options items="${agecy}" itemLabel="agecyName" itemValue="agecyCode"/>
        </form:select>
</td>
<td class="label">
    <form:label path="cate">
            <span class="requiredFieldMarker"><fmt:message key="label.requiredMarker"/></span><fmt:message key="label.cate"/><fmt:message key="label.postfix"/>
    </form:label>
</td>
<td class="data" >
    <form:select path="cate">
        <form:option value=""><fmt:message key="label.select"/></form:option>
        <form:options items="${refcate}" itemValue="refCode" itemLabel="refDesc"/>
    </form:select>
</td>
<td class="label">
    <form:label path="level">
            <span class="requiredFieldMarker"><fmt:message key="label.requiredMarker"/></span><fmt:message key="label.level"/><fmt:message key="label.postfix"/>
    </form:label>
</td>
<td class="data" >
    <form:select path="level">
        <form:option value=""><fmt:message key="label.select"/></form:option>
        <form:options items="${refLevel}" itemValue="refCode" itemLabel="refDesc"/>
    </form:select>
</td>
<td class="label">
    <form:label path="noOfQuestions">
            <span class="requiredFieldMarker"><fmt:message key="label.requiredMarker"/></span><fmt:message key="label.noofQuestions"/><fmt:message key="label.postfix"/>
    </form:label>
</td>
<td class="data" >
    <form:input path="noOfQuestions" maxlength="3" size="5"/>
</td>
</c:choose>
<c:otherwise>
<td class="label">
    <form:label path="cate">
            <span class="requiredFieldMarker"><fmt:message key="label.requiredMarker"/></span><fmt:message key="label.cate"/><fmt:message key="label.postfix"/>
    </form:label>
</td>
<td class="data" >
    <form:select path="cate">
        <form:option value=""><fmt:message key="label.select"/></form:option>
        <form:options items="${refcate}" itemValue="refCode" itemLabel="refDesc"/>
    </form:select>
</td>
<td class="label">
    <form:label path="level">
            <span class="requiredFieldMarker"><fmt:message key="label.requiredMarker"/></span><fmt:message key="label.level"/><fmt:message key="label.postfix"/>
    </form:label>
</td>
<td class="data" >
    <form:select path="level">
        <form:option value=""><fmt:message key="label.select"/></form:option>
        <form:options items="${refLevel}" itemValue="refCode" itemLabel="refDesc"/>
        </form:select>
</td>
<td class="label">
    <form:label path="noOfQuestions">
            <span class="requiredFieldMarker"><fmt:message key="label.requiredMarker"/></span><fmt:message key="label.noofQuestions"/><fmt:message key="label.postfix"/>
    </form:label>
</td>
<td class="data" >
    <form:input path="noOfQuestions" maxlength="3" size="5"/>
</td>
</c:otherwise>
</tr>       
</tbody>
```

Comment: And the nested exception is...? Why one does not simply paste whole stacktrace?

Comment: because both link have different business -Antoniossss

Comment: org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException this is the exception - Antoniossss